Table filter not shown VueJS
I would like to be able to filter the dates shown in my data table and have followed a demo to do so. This should be relatively simple but nothing is being shown despite the requirements for a filter being met.
These are the imports and data of the file that shows the table:
import CoreLibrary from "../../../../core/helpers/CoreLibrary.js";
import * as actions from "../../../Config/ApiUrl";
import { TableHelpers } from "./TableHelpers";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: "Biometricos",
    mixins: [TableHelpers],
    extends: [CoreLibrary],
    data() {
        return {
            salidaDescription: '',
            salidaLocation: '',
            momentInstance: moment(),
            searchValue: '',
            deleteLoader: false,
            isAddEditModalActive: false,
            isInfoModalActive: false,
            deleteConformationModalActive: false,
            selectedUrl: '',
            tableId: '',
            options: {
                id: '',
                name: 'biometricos-table',
                isAddEditModalActive: false,
                isInfoModalActive: false,
                url: `${actions.BIOMETRICOS}/index`,
                showHeader: true,
                showCount: true,
                showClearFilter: true,
                columns: [],
                filters: [
                    {
                        "title": this.$t('date'),
                        "type": "range-picker",
                        "key": "date",
                        "option": ["today", "thisMonth", "last7Days", "nextYear"]
                    },
                ],
                actions: [
                    {
                        title: 'Info',
                        icon: 'eye',
                        type: 'none',
                        component: 'InfoModal',
                    }
                ],
                paginationType: "pagination",
                responsive: true,
                rowLimit: 10,
                orderBy: 'asc',
                datatableWrapper: false,
                showFilter: true,
                showSearch: true,
                showAction: true,
            },

        }
    },

This is how I am invoking the table:
<app-table :id="'biometricos-table'" :options="options" @action="getListAction" />

Any help is much appreciated, I am worried that it is a silly fix, but I simply cannot find what is wrong.

removing datatableWrapper: false allows for the filters to show. I believe that the wrapper was somehow blocking the filters even though it was set to false.
